# How to check if specific rows in sql database are not empty or null and get value if true

Tags: power-automate

I have flow in Power automate that looks like this:

Manually trigger **->** Get rows(SQL database) **->** Apply to Each wrapper **->** Get items(SP) **->** Condition `length(body('Get_items')?['value']) is greater than or equal to 1` **->** if true **->** do nothing **->** if false **->** Create item(SP)

It works as it is now, but i want to add some new data to the SP the data is already in the database.
The SP list is about showing upcoming events, it has the usual data like, title, date, time, location.

I want to add the room the event takes place in, but the database is setup like this, it has a header for each location where the user writes the room name, so i have to go through every column in that row and if the column is not empty " " or null then get the value.

[image: Screenshot from database]

my idea is in the "Create Item(SP)" to just have one column for the room and with an expression go  over the rows and if not empty or null then get value.